# Please remove this question from my "failed review" list

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

As I'm into reviewing some questions, the following appeared, which looks like "*I want to design some software, and I would like to use some buttons in the GUI. I have two ideas but I don't know which one is better*".

Such a question can be seen as:

- Ok : it's about software design and you have a doubt about which choice to make.
- Nok: can you be more specific?

Seen the possible doubt, I've mentioned this question as being ok, but then I got the "STOP! Look and Listen!" warning, which tells me I'm a bad reviewer.

I know there are some lousy questions and that review audits (with the "STOP! Look and Listen!" warnings) are a way to ensure the quality of the review process, but this one is really too harsh, so please remove it from my "Failed review" counter.

As the question itself has been deleted, hereby a screenshot of my review result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not a moderator, but if I am correctly informed, moderators don't have the power to change your "failed review counter", which is managed by some automatisms of the site.

However, I would not overreact on this. Failing such a test can happen to anyone, since neither the system isn't perfect, nor our reviewers. According to [this Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) post, it is likely that nothing will happen. Only in the very unlikely case you fail these tests repeatedly in short succession, the system will give you a break of a few days on reviewing, no less, no more. As long as you don't act in bad faith, you won't loose rep or get any suspension for asking or answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than worry about a meaningless stat might I suggest that if the difference between "primary" and "secondary" buttons was clear to you then an edit to make it clear to the rest of us would have been welcome.

I hate losing good questions because few people understand what is being asked. So if you can see what they mean please help the rest of us.

<sup>Seriously, what's a secondary button?</sup>

Comment: Did I understand that correctly - you suggest the OP should edit a question which was already deleted in the past (and only became visible again for a short time because it was picked by the review test bot)?

Comment: @DocBrown yes. An activity which would have prevented getting a fail.